# Notification animation, only on Galaxy nexus

Tags: android, notifications, galaxy, foreground

I have a foreground service with a notification that I update every second as a timer. This works fine on my android 4.1 emulator. On a Galaxy Nexus phone the notification shows up as a new notification with a animation on each update. Why is that? Same android version, but I only found this behavior on Galaxy Nexus.

```
private void postNotification(Context context, int notificationId, String title, String text, String ticker, boolean service) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);        
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationId, intent, 0);

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(text);
    if(ticker.length() > 0)
        builder.setTicker(ticker);      
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(service);

    nm.notify(null, notificationId, builder.getNotification()); 
    startForeground(notificationId, builder.getNotification());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was another app that ran in the notification bar as a service that made this behavior. Worked after that app was uninstalled.